# Continuation principle for a PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I read some papers that study the global existence of a solution to a PDE. Sometimes, I found the notion of the "continuation principle".

What do we mean by the continuation principle? any recommended references and thank you in advance.

Comment: Typically, a continuation criterion is a criterion which, if satisfied, guarantees that the solution to a PDE exists for all time. For example, the Beale-Kato-Majda criterion says that if the vorticity remains bounded, the solution to the Euler equations exists for all time: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-94/issue-1/Remarks-on-the-breakdown-of-smooth-solutions-for-the-3/cmp/1103941230.full